# Download PDF that should work across every browser

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I am currently running into an issue where I need to download pdf on anchor button click which is placed inside a bootstrap modal window.

Please help how this can be achieved.
I tried using HTML5 "download" attribute but this does not work in IE and safari.
and also clicking on this link in Firefox and chrome, does not download the pdf.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of IE and safari?

Comment: `clicking on this link in Firefox and chrome, does not download the pdf` what happens instead? seems like your code is broken for **every** browser

Comment: what is the backend, and is their a specific mechanism that you're using or any kind of library?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX,
 I tried this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download in IE 10 and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @imixtron,
The pdf link is coming from the hybris cms cockpit that gets binded to the anchor tag href property.

Answer (score 1):

There is way to force PDF files to be downloaded and not just opened in browser when you link to them. This way you wouldn't need to mess with HTML5 browser support.

All you have to do is to add this line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Oh yeah, I forgot. On your button just add `<a href="pdf location">button</a>` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The [download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_download.asp) attribute is not supported in IE, Safari or Opera version 12 (and earlier)
So, check the browser version.